# How to duplicate NamespaceURI declaration in Java package-info

Tags: java, xml, soap

I have a package-info.java class defined, and I need to generate a xml file with all the xmlns defined here:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "dian:gov:co:facturaelectronica:NominaIndividual", 
    elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED, xmlns = {
        @XmlNs(prefix = "", namespaceURI = "dian:gov:co:facturaelectronica:NominaIndividual"),
        @XmlNs(prefix = "ds", namespaceURI = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"),
        @XmlNs(prefix = "ext", namespaceURI = "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2"),
        @XmlNs(prefix = "cbc", namespaceURI = "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2"),
        @XmlNs(prefix = "cac", namespaceURI = "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2"),
        @XmlNs(prefix = "xades", namespaceURI = "http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#"),
        @XmlNs(prefix = "xades141", namespaceURI = "http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.4.1#"),
        @XmlNs(prefix = "xs",  namespaceURI = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"),
        @XmlNs(prefix = "xsi", namespaceURI = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")})
        
package com.sifactura.nomina.imports.dian.gov.co.facturaelectronica.nominaindividual;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs;
```

In the resultant xml, prefix xs it's deleted.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<NominaIndividual SchemaLocation="" 
    xmlns="dian:gov:co:facturaelectronica:NominaIndividual" 
    xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" 
    xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" 
    xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" 
    xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2" 
    xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" 
    xmlns:xades141="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.4.1#" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="dian:gov:co:facturaelectronica:NominaIndividual NominaIndividualElectronicaXSD.xsd">
```

I assume because namespaceURI it's defined twice,but I need both namespace. There is any configuration to keep al XmlNs prefix defined?

**EDIT: 21/03/2022**
I ended up with adding programmatically that namespace with:

```
Node nodeNs = document.getDocumentElement();
        ((Element)nodeNs).setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/",
                   "xmlns:xs", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
```

Comment: Why don't you add your solution as an actual answer, so others know that this has a proper answer? You can even mark it as accepted some time after you publish it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: 21/03/2022 I ended up with adding programmatically that namespace with

```
Node nodeNs = document.getDocumentElement();
((Element)nodeNs).setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/",
               "xmlns:xs", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
```